# How can mwclient access a wiki behind https?

Tags: python, mediawiki

I want to use mwclient to edit an internal wiki behind HTTPS.  [This page](https://github.com/mwclient/mwclient) suggests that you can pass in a host tuple like this:

> site = mwclient.Site(('https','wiki.whatever.com'))

However I don't see how to authenticate with Apache.  Do you need to set up a urllib2 opener handler with the authentication?

A solution that works with python-wikitools would alternatively be welcome, but also has a lack of https examples.

Update:
Perhaps it uses the same user ID and password as you're using to login to the wiki?  I still get an error in that case though:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\ddc\DDC_Toolbox\python_root\apps\create_new_project\trunk\create_new_project.py", line 36, in <module>
>       site = mwclient.Site(('https',url))
>     File "C:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\mwclient-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\mwclient\client.py", line 92, in __init__
>       self.site_init()
>     File "C:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\mwclient-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\mwclient\client.py", line 100, in site_init
>       siprop = 'general|namespaces', uiprop = 'groups|rights')
>     File "C:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\mwclient-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\mwclient\client.py", line 165, in api
>       info = self.raw_api(action, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\mwclient-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\mwclient\client.py", line 248, in raw_api
>       json_data = self.raw_call('api', data).read()
>     File "C:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\mwclient-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\mwclient\client.py", line 223, in raw_call
>       url, data = data, headers = headers)
>     File "C:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\mwclient-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\mwclient\http.py", line 226, in post
>       path, headers, data)
>     File "C:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\mwclient-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\mwclient\http.py", line 161, in post
>       return self.request('POST', host, path, headers, data)
>     File "C:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\mwclient-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\mwclient\http.py", line 152, in request
>       raise errors.HTTPStatusError, (res.status, res)
>   mwclient.errors.HTTPStatusError: (401, <httplib.HTTPResponse instance at 0x0241C0D0>)`

Comment: Actually, I think mwclient supports HTTPS but doesn't support authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `mwclient` doesn't use urllib2, so installing an urllib2 AuthHandler won't do anything.

It's using `httplib`, and from a quick look at the source, there seems to be no way to add your own headers to the requests sent by the library, so adding a custom Authorization header won't work without modifying the library itself.

`python-wikitools` on the other hand uses `urllib2`, but [instantiates it's own opener](http://code.google.com/p/python-wikitools/source/browse/trunk/wikitools/api.py?r=384#88), and to be able to add an auth handler to that, you'd also need to modify the library-

So, unfortunately both apis don't allow you to use authentication out of the box.

Comment: It looks to me that `python-wikitools` uses `urllib2`.  In the link you sent it imports `urllib2` and not `httplib2`.

Comment: yes, of course I ment `urllib2`, got a bit confused with all the libraries :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to add HTTPS authentication to python-wikitools.  I'll see about getting a patch uploaded to the maintainers of the package.